# without refresh page when using the back button in MVC .NET Core

Tags: model-view-controller, .net-core

I have an EditController, when I edit the invalid value in this controller and click the Next button. It is navigation to ErrorController. 
In the ErrorController, I using return RedirectToAction("Index", "Edit") to back a EditController and refresh page.
How I can back an EditController without refresh page. Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use RedirectToAction, but instead `ReturnView("Index","Edit");`